# Angularjs ng-show from child scope to parent scope not refreshing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-show

I haven't found, despite the many similar questions, how to hide a DOM element with `ng-show` in a parent scope from a child scope.

I've got two nested controllers.
In the parent one (attached to ), I'm using the youtube embed directive to be able to read the video continuously despite changing views in `ng-view`.

```
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
  <body>
    <youtube-video id="player" ... ng-show="selectedVideo.showVideo"></youtube-video>
    <div ng-view></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I first reach a route defined in ngRoute, the parent controller methods are called and in both controller I can decide to show or hide the video with

```
$scope.selectedVideo.showVideo = true;
```

And the video is displayed or hidden as I wish.

However, when I use the **back button**, the parent controller methods are not called, but I call nevertheless

```
$scope.selectedVideo.showVideo = false;
```

*But the video still shows...*

And at that point, when I refresh the page entirely (and manually...) the video finally gets hidden.

I'm not sure to understand why this is the case...

I basically would like to have some ngRoute views that display the video, and other which don't.
That is, I would like the ng-show from the parent controller to be set to true/false from the child controller...

*Any idea how can I achieve that?*

I tried to use `$scope.$parent` with both an object as above and a primitive, but that didn't change a thing.

It's as the actual value used for ng-show is updated but ng-show being out of the ngView isn't refreshed...

Comment: Can get a lot of information about current route by using routeChange events. Not clear what determines video state but sounds like a simple service combined with routeParams would help you a lot

Comment: How's routeChange linked to refreshing the Dom outside of the ngView?

Comment: can listen to routeChange outside of ngView. It's a broadcast from $rootScope. For example a navbar that is outside of ngView...can set active states using it

Comment: Ok I'll try, I asked because I didn't think that would be possible. Thanks I'll let you know

Comment: try `$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(current){ console.log(current) })` in your outer controller

Comment: That worked thanks ;) Plus the fact that I had to wrap the youtubeEmbed directive into a div and use ng-if instead of ng-show. Maybe you could write your comments as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the parent controller you can listen for all route changes using:

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(current){ 
    console.log(current) 
});
```

Then using the properties of the current route you should be able to manage your video player by setting the appropriate scope variables

Comment: It's really helped me.. Thanks